# Disabling javascript files on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am working on a website and the homepage is very javascript/jQuery heavy. Because of this there are all sorts of issues on mobile devices when loading the page. Mobile Safari crashes and on other devices the page freezes completely.

I would like to know if it is possible to disable an external javascript file, if the website detects that you are using a mobile device.

Comment: Yes, it is possible by sniffing the user agent. Best done server-side in this case, though i'd suggest making the site less heavy and use media queries to optimize the layout for mobile rather than using user agent sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

You have two main choices:

1. At the beginning of the external javascript file, check what kind of device you're on and skip executing the rest of the file if desired.
2. Don't statically load the javascript file.  Instead, check what kind of device and then dynamically load the JS file if not on a mobile device.

That said, what you really ought to do is fix your javascript because there's no reason you can't have javascript that works on both desktop and mobile devices.  If mobile Safari is crashing that's because you have issues in your JS that you should fix, not because you can't run JS on mobile Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response, I will probably try option 1. The problem is that it is using a parallax scrolling effect via Stellar.js which I have heard does not work well with mobile browsers since scrolling works differently.